# Can Windows 10 iot on Raspberry Pi 3 run java program well?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

i got an assignment on running programs in Raspberry Pi 3. The assignment is to make a program that can simulate a parking gate via Raspberry Pi 3, so it will contain commands like printing from the usb and receiving input via button. My main programming language is java, so i'm planning to use java for the Raspberry Pi 3. 
So can Windows 10 IOT run most of the basic functions in Java?

Comment: @Yahya: You've missed the crucial part of the Pi running Windows 10 IOT.

Comment: If you install Raspbian Desktop, open a console and type "sudo apt install default-jdk" then you have Java installed and can jun java, javac or simply double click a JAR file to run it.Use FileZilla to copy files from a Windows computer to the Pi (SFTP port 22). Very simple and easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today nobody has ported Java to Windows IOT for ARM CPUs. It looks equally bleak for other software packages.

Java runs just fine on the Raspberry Pi on Linux, which is the preferred OS for Raspberry anyway.

As for the reason, well outside of education no sane person would want to use Windows IOT it seems. With no commercial interest there is incentive for companies to provide support. And Microsoft seems to spend more money in marketing WindowsIOT then actually investing into software.

Comment: Thanks, i switched to raspbian and starting to use Phyton 3 with Java. Works well